# Leaking in constructor

Tags: c++

Do I leak if I allocate memory with new in the constructor of an object and immediately after I throw an exception?

The object shouldn't be constructed at all and thus no destructor will be called, but what about that memory?

e.g.

```
MyObject() {
  data = new char[200]; // Will this be leaked?

  if(something_is_wrong)
    throw exception();

}
```

Comment: Yes, use something that owns that memory and behaves properly like `std::string`.

Comment: What type is `data`? `data` will be destructed so if it is of a type that expects to manage the memory assigned to it there might not be a leak.

Comment: yes, it definetely leak

Comment: Never acquire a resource that needs manually freeing in a constructor unless the sole purpose of the class is to manage that resource.

Answer (score 4):

It will leak. Once you have gotten a pointer from `new` it eventually needs to be `delete`d. The solution is to make `data` a smart pointer (or in this case, probably a `std::string`); while `MyObject`'s destructor won't be called, data members' destructors *are* called.

Comment: You don't know if `data` won't cleanup after itself, though, so it's just a guess. It is *possible* for that code to leak memory.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm assuming `data` is something like `char*` in his example.

Comment: Yeah, my point precisely. Before you know (ask the OP) it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: if the OP were using a smart pointer to clean up, wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf throwing more assumptions at the problem seems really weird for me, especially if you can just ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will be a leak unless `data` is kind of *handle*, *smart pointer* and not a raw pointer `char* data`. A safe variant of this is:

```
class MyObject {

        std::vector<char> data; // or some handle/smart pointer (i.e. unique_ptr)
                                // it might be just std::string
    public:
        MyObject( int sz) : data( sz) {}
};
```

In this case the memory used is now managed by vector. You can of course do it by yourself what is actually done in vector already and is exception safe. This is you can use approach similar to `std::uninitialized_fill`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz data is a vector in my example

Comment: Ah, my bad, I meant OP's `data`.

Comment: true, I've assumed in OP's example data is raw pointer char* data, edited

Comment: Might want to mention the best-suited smart-pointer (`std::unique_ptr`), and the semantically far superior `std::string`. Also worth to mention (because the OP uses a constant size), is just adding the array directly to the class, instead of a pointer to it.

Comment: It looks like just a coincidence that size is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Unless `data` is a *smart pointer* (or, more generally, any object that frees the memory passed to it when it destructs) you will leak memory.

The `new` will need to be balanced with a `delete[]` (note the `[]`). It's important to note that, since a `MyObject` instance was not created, the destructor to `MyObject` will **not** be called so you cannot rely on any memory cleanup there.

Two alternatives.

1. free the memory before the `throw` statement.
2. Make `data` a smart pointer (if it isn't already).

2 is preferred - by exploiting RAII it makes code more stable.

Comment: You don't know if `data` isn't a smart pointer already, though.

Answer (score 1):

The situation that you sketch,

```
MyObject() {
  data = new char[200]; // Will this be leaked?

  if(something_is_wrong)
    throw exception();

}
```

will<sup>1</sup> leak unless automatic garbage collection is used (and even so it may still leak).

This case is very easily dealt with by using an appropriate standard library container:

```
MyObject()
{
  string data( 200, '\0' );
  if(something_is_wrong)
    throw exception();
}
```

And in general preferentially use standard library containers instead of all this new'ing, and if there isn't a suitable container, use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`.

In short, there's not really a problem, not any more than a call to `std::terminate` is a problem (just remove the call, or don't do it in the first place).

---

However, if you define a custom allocation function for the class, and forget to define a corresponding deallocation function, then throwing an exception from a constructor can leak memory.

As a learner simply don't define allocation functions.

As a professional remember to do it properly if at some time you should really need it.

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> Under the reasonable assumption that you're not using a smart pointer to guarantee cleanup *and* asking this question without mentioning the smart pointer.</sup>